# Pythonのデータ結合についての質問です。

Tags: python, pandas

Pythonのデータ結合についての質問です。

seriesに対し、日付をkeyにしてdf1を左外部結合するやり方を教えていただけませんか。

```
series＝pd.series ([‘1/1’,’1/2’,…..’1/10’],name=‘日付’)
df1=pd.DataFrame ({‘日付’:[‘1/1’,’1/2’,…..’1/7’], {‘天気’:[‘晴れ,’’曇り’,…..’曇り’]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)

series = pd.Series(
  ['1/1', '1/2', '1/3', '1/4', '1/5', '1/6', '1/7', '1/8', '1/9', '1/10'],
  name='日付')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  '日付': ['1/1', '1/2', '1/3', '1/4', '1/5', '1/6', '1/7'],
  '天気': ['晴れ', '晴れ', '曇り', '晴れ', '曇り', '曇り', '晴れ'],
})

dfx = pd.merge(series, df1, on='日付', how='left')
#dfx = df1.set_index('日付').reindex(series).reset_index()
print(dfx)

#
   日付  天気
0   1/1  晴れ
1   1/2  晴れ
2   1/3  曇り
3   1/4  晴れ
4   1/5  曇り
5   1/6  曇り
6   1/7  晴れ
7   1/8   NaN
8   1/9   NaN
9  1/10   NaN
```